# finding $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{(1+x) -√(1-x)}/x$?

Tags: limits

I started by multiplying the top and the bottom by $\sqrt{(1+x)+(1-X)}$ I'm just not sure if that is the right way to start it. The answer should come out to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is.  When you finish simplifying the top,  you get the top is 2 and the bottom is just what you multiplied by, and then you plug in 0 to get 2/2=1.